# Flowable To LiveData through LiveDataReactiveStreams doesn't work

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room, android-livedata

I'm using room and I want to synchronize a LiveData with the result of a DB request
I'm doing this :

dao

```
    @Query("SELECT Pet.* FROM Pet WHERE user_Id = :userId " +
            "UNION " +
            "SELECT Pet.* FROM PetFeeders INNER JOIN Pet ON PetFeeders.pet_Id = Pet.pet_id " +
            "WHERE PetFeeders.user_Id = :userId")
    Flowable<List<Pet>> getAllUserPetsByUserId(Long userId);
```

repository

```
    private LiveData<List<Pet>> userPets;

    public void setUserPets(LiveData<List<Pet>> userPets) {
        this.userPets = userPets;
    }

    @Override
    public Flowable<List<Pet>> getAllUserPetsByUserId(Long userId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "getAllUserPetsByUserId(" + userId + ")");
        return petFoodingControlDatabase.getPetDao().getAllUserPetsByUserId(userId)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }
```

service

```
    @Override
    public void setUserPets(User user) {
        pfcRepository.setUserPets(LiveDataReactiveStreams
                .fromPublisher(pfcRepository.getAllUserPetsByUserId(user.getUserId())));
    }
```

The request works correctly, but the LiveData is never fed. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Maybe the `LiveData` object is not active?

Comment: What do you mean by not active ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

Comment: How do you observe the userPets? You replace the whole `LiveData` object so maybe you don't create a new observer for it? [this](https://gist.github.com/akarnokd/25b042ca3008e3729c6064c89ef4b7ae) works for me.